# How to delete coma of numbers contained in the dataframe's column?

Tags: python, pandas

Values of column "Daily Oil Consumption (Barrels)" contain comas . i would delete this because this variable considered as object not a intiger.

Comment: Does this help: [search-and-replace-dots-and-commas-in-pandas-dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49088443/search-and-replace-dots-and-commas-in-pandas-dataframe). Also here: [convert-number-strings-with-commas-in-pandas-dataframe-to-float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22137723/convert-number-strings-with-commas-in-pandas-dataframe-to-float)

Comment: i want to delete the comas contained in the third column "Daily Oil Consumption (Barrels) " because this variable is considered as object but not as  integer.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the commas just use the **str.replace()** function.

```
>>> my_text = "Hi, my name is Kaleb"
>>> my_text = my_text.replace(",","")
>>>
>>>
>>> print(my_text)
Hi my name is Kaleb
```

Inside the parenthesis the first parameter is the old text, the second parameter is the text you want to replace it with.

In this case you want to replace a "," with nothing, so just "".

Here's an example:

```
df['Daily Oil Consumption (Barrels)'] = df['Daily Oil Consumption (Barrels)'].str.replace(',', '')
```

Answer (score 1):

Just expanding the @KalebFenley answer, you need to do the replacement to remove the commas

```py
df['Daily Oil Consumption (Barrels)'] = df['Daily Oil Consumption (Barrels)'].str.replace(',', '')
```

And also, as @Yousef mentioned, you need to cast it as int, the full line of code should be something like this.

```py
df['Daily Oil Consumption (Barrels)'] = df['Daily Oil Consumption (Barrels)'].str.replace(',', '').astype(int)
```

And that should work for this specific case, however, my personal recommendation is that you should use the pandas function "[to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)", because in that way you can avoid exceptions if your data includes some "non-numeric" values.

```py
df['Daily Oil Consumption (Barrels)'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Daily Oil Consumption (Barrels)'], errors='coerce')
```

If you don't have that issue, just proceed with the previous suggestion.

Comment: thank you , the code works

Comment: Just in case, I've already added another option that would work if you have data that  is not a number, however, if you strictly want to have integers the existing suggestions should be enough and would notify you when you have dirty data. @emmanuel

Answer (score 0):

I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38516583/7813774) can help you.

So, you can do this:

```
df1['Daily Oil Consumption (Barrels)'] = df1['Daily Oil Consumption (Barrels)'].str.replace(',', '')
df1['Daily Oil Consumption (Barrels)'] = df1['Daily Oil Consumption (Barrels)'].astype(int)
```